# Using flex with react native maps?

Tags: react-native, flexbox, react-native-maps

`absoluteFillObject` it's the only way to get map working?

I want to distribute the screen in this way

```
map - flex 3

bottom layout (eg taxi details) - flex 1
```

but I can't get the map working with flex (variable size) without getting an error about the map size can't be 0

It's important the map don't use the whole screen because the center of the map it's not the center of the screen since we have a bottom layout using part of the screen

As a workaround i use marginBottom to avoid the bottom layout height but that way I have to give a fixed height to the bottom layout and I lose the flexible size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
           <View style={{width:'100%', height:'100%'}}>
                <Map style={{width:'100%', height:'75%'}}></Map>
                <OtherComponent style={{width:'100%', height:'25%'}}></OtherComponent>
            </View>
```

I faced same issue with Map and flex combination. I just give height in percentage and its work for me. You can try with above code for your solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The Nirmalsinh's solution work, but I would suggest just wrap the map view in a flex container, e.g.:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <MapView height: '100%'}}/>
  </View>
  </OtherComponent>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
<View style={styles.container}>
   <MapView
     style={styles.map}
    />         
</View>
```

and the styles,

```
 container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    height: 540, // you can customize this
    width: 400,  // you can customize this
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  map: {
   ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject
  }
```